# opening a linked python executable file from another linked python executable file opens cmd

Tags: python

I have built 7 individual calculators:

1. Basic Calculator
2. Scientific Calculator
3. Bitwise Calculator
4. Binary → All Calculator
5. Decimal → All
6. Octal → All
7. Hexadecimal → All

works very fine **INDIVIDUALLY**

In order to open each program, I've created a floating window that connects all programs in one.
But when I open each calculator from there the CMD opens.

```
 import os
 import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import messagebox

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = Tk()
    menu = Menu(o)

    new = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=new)


    def new_window():
        os.system('Calculator.exe')


    new.add_command(label='New', command=new_window)
    about = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_cascade(label='About', menu=about)
    about.add_command(label='Version 1.0', command=None)


    def ExitApplication():
        msg_box = tk.messagebox.askquestion('Exit Application', 'Are you sure you want to exit the application',
                                           icon='warning')
        if msg_box == 'yes':
            o.destroy()
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo('Return', 'Return to the application window')


    exit_click = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
    menu.add_cascade(label='More', menu=exit_click)
    exit_click.add_command(label='Exit', command=ExitApplication)

    o.config(menu=menu)

    o.title("Calculator Options")
    o.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file="calculator.png"))
    o.geometry("500x521")
    o.config(relief=SUNKEN, bg="#ADD8E6")


    def click_basic():
        os.system('Basic_Calculator.exe')


    def click_scientific():
        os.system('Scientific_Calculator.exe')


    def click_binary_to_all():
        os.system('Binary_to_All.exe')

    def click_octal_to_all():
        os.system('Oct_to_All.exe')

    def click_decimal_to_all():
        os.system('Dec_to_All.exe')

    def click_hex_to_all():
        os.system('Hex_to_All.exe')

    def click_bitwise():
        os.system('Bitwise_Operations.exe')

    def button():
        Button(o, bg="#BCD4E6", fg="black", relief="groove", text="Basic", font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"),
               command=click_basic).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        Button(o, bg="#89CFF0", fg="black", relief="groove", text="Scientific", font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"),
               command=click_scientific).pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        Button(o, bg="#BCD4E6", fg="black", relief="groove", text="Bin → Oct, Dec, Hex", font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"),
               command=click_binary_to_all).pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        Button(o, bg="#89CFF0", fg="black", relief="groove", text="Oct → Bin, Dec, Hex", font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"),
               command=click_octal_to_all).pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        Button(o, bg="#BCD4E6", fg="black", relief="groove", text="Dec → Bin, Oct, Hex",
               font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"), command=click_decimal_to_all).pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        Button(o, bg="#89CFF0", fg="black", relief="groove", text="Hex → Bin, Oct, Dec",
               font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"), command=click_hex_to_all).pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        Button(o, bg="#BCD4E6", fg="black", relief="groove", text="Bitwise Operations",
               font=("Times New Roman", 16, "bold"), command=click_bitwise).pack(fill='both', expand=True)


    button()
    o.mainloop()
```

This is my floating window code.

I've embedded an example too.

Clicking on the Basic option opens the Basic Calculator fine but also opens the CMD disabling the Floating Window https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYGmf.png